# How can I add a string character based on a position in OpenRefine?

Tags: openrefine, grel

I have a column in Openrefine, which I would like to add a character string in each of its rows, based on the position in the string.
For example:
I have an 8th character number string: 85285296  and would like to add "-" at the fourth place: "8528-5296".
Anyone can help me find the specific function in OpenRefine?

Thanks

Tzipy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible solution (not sure if it's the most straightforward):

```
value.replace(/(\d{4})(.+)/, "$1-$2")
```

This means : if $1 represents the content of the first parenthesis/group in the regular expression before and $2 the content of the second one, replaces each value in the column with $1-$2.

Comment: Very clever, but not very approachable for a novice, in my opinion. Regexs are a pretty advanced topic.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest approach is to just use the expression language's built-in string indexing and concatenation:

`value[0,4]+'-'+value[4,8]`

or more generally, if you don't know that your value is exactly 8 characters long:

`value[0,4]+'-'+value[4,999]`

Answer (score 1):

Some other options:

```
value.splitByLengths(4,4).join("-")

value.match(/(\d{4})(\d{4})/).join("-")

value.substring(0,4)+"-"+value.substring(4,8)
```

I think 'splitByLengths' is the neatest, but I might use 'match' instead because it fails with an error if your starting string isn't 8 digits - which means you don't accidentally process data that doesn't conform to your assumption of what data is in the column - but you could use a facet/filter to check this with any of the others